# Php email form not sending email from web email form

Tags: php

I am trying to troubleshoot this form. It is not sending reservation requests from the form on the website. Despite showing a message that the form was sent.

I tried editing email and the headers.

```
<?
//print_r($_POST);

$to = “email@emaildomain.com, {$posting['email']}";
function msg($text){
echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('".$text."');
    top.location.href = 'http://www.aribbq.com';
    </script>
";
exit;
}

function error($text){
echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('".$text."');
    history.go(-1);
    </script>
";
exit;
}

if (!$_POST[date]) {error('Please, insert Date.');}
if (!$_POST[time]) {error('Please, insert Time.');}
if (!$_POST[party]) {error('Please, insert Party.');}
if (!$_POST[reservation_name]) {error('Please, insert Name.');}
if (!$_POST[reservation_email]) {error('Please, insert Email.');}
if (!$_POST[reservation_phone]) {error('Please, insert Phone.');}  
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 // then send the form to your email

//$from = ('Reservation from AriBBQ.com'); // sender
$mailheaders = "From: contact@aribbq.com" . "\r\n"; // . "CC: 
design@youremail.com"
$mailheaders .= 'Reply-To: ' . $posting['Email'] . "\r\n";
$subject = "AriBBQ.com Online Reservation";
$body = "\n Contact Name: ".$_POST[reservation_name]." \r\n\n"; 
//
$body .= " Email: ".$_POST[reservation_email]." \r\n\n"; //
$body .= " =================================================== \r\n\n"; //
$body .= "  Book a table \r\n\n
            Date: ".$_POST[date]." \r\n\n
            Time: ".$_POST[time]." \r\n\n
            Party: ".$_POST[party]." \r\n\n
            Contact Details \r\n\n
            Name: ".$_POST[reservation_name]." \r\n\n
            Email: ".$_POST[reservation_email]." \r\n\n
            Phone: ".$_POST[reservation_phone]." \r\n\n
            Message: ".$_POST[reservation_message]." \r\n\n"; //
$body .= " =================================================== \r\n\n"; //


$result = mail($to , $from , $subject , $body , $mailheaders); 
if($result) {msg('Thank you, your reservation has been sent. We 
will send you a confirmation text or call in person.');} // 
else{error('Sending mail is failed. Please try again');} //

} else {
error('No submitted. Please try again');
}

?>
```

You see the form online at http://aribbq.com/. Click on reservations. Once the email is received, we want to be able to reply to the sender's email address.

Comment: try and change your opening tag to `<?php`, `<?` is used by xml. Not sure if it'll make a difference but start from the top, eh? =)

Comment: I changed it and loaded it, but no difference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I notice you're using `$_POST` for all your data except for the `$to` address, you use `$posting`, is that intentional? Also, add temporarily `error_reporting( E_ALL );` to your script to see if you get any errors.

Comment: You're from address is commented out.  You will need to remove all of the arbitrary comment slashes at the end and clean up your code (formatting) to help people troubleshoot at a glance.  Also - did this work prior?  What do you mean by sending reservation requests - do you mean email?  Another suggestion - create a very simple php mail script with just hard coded values to ensure that you can indeed invoke the mail command successfully from the server where the script resides.  Then work backwards from there.

Comment: Could it be the curly quote (left double quote) on `$to = “email@emaildomain.com, {$posting['email']}";`? Those are not interpreted the same as regular quotes. Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Also relevant: [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](//stackoverflow.com/q/24644436)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I will turn on error reporting and follow Tim's advice and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you need to turn on error reporting because your script threw about 20 errors at me which you would see with error reporting on. As my comment above said, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script while you debug.

The issues I came across are as follows:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in /mail.php on line 4` caused by an incorrect double quote character, not `"` but `“`. Subtle, but problematic.

Next up, `Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /mail.php` because as of PHP 5.5.2, a [bug was fixed](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68776) to prevent mail header injection, so all of your `\n\n` within the `$mailheaders` should be removed, I recommend appending `PHP_EOL` to the end of each line instead.

You have your `$from` variable included in the `mail()` call, this presents 2 issues. One, the `mail()` function does not have a *from* parameter, you include it within the headers. Two - your variable is actually commented out.

As I mentioned in the comment above, again, your email address variable to send to is typed as `$posting['email']'`, and `$posting['Email']` within `$mailheaders`. The problem here is `$posting` doesn't exist. Secondly, your form, doesn't post `email` at all, it posts `reservation_email`.

Finally, the majority of your `$_POST` references do not include quotes so PHP doesn't know what to do with the words in between the square brackets. `$_POST[date]` should be `$_POST['date']`, for example.

I've made all the above changes and managed to successfully email myself with the script and email form provided, the only thing that I didn't look at was your `msg()` which didn't show me a success message. I did, however, put an `echo` statement before this function call which printed out fine.

I hope this helps you get your script up and running, good luck and remember, `error_reporting();` is your friend!

Comment: Thank you so much! I put the reply to email in the mail headers  
$mailheaders .= 'Reply-To: ' . ['reservation_email'] . "\r\n"; and fixed the $_POST references. Also, I discovered a typo in my email address for testing it. :-P After fixing all of this and loading it, it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, no problem. Sometimes all you need is a fresh set of eyes and a break!